# Gerar um contexto de uma outra instancia no CreateView

Tags: c, django, django-templates, django-queryset

Olá! 
Estou precisando de renderizar um contexto no template do CreateView.

no requeste to passando um id, e quero colocar o nome referente desse id no template do CreateView

> url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('editar_receita/<int:pk>', ReceitaEditar.as_view(), 
   name='add_ingrediente')
]
```

> view.py

```
class ReceitaEditar(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = ProdutoReceita
    form_class = ProdutoRceitaForm


def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(ReceitaEditar, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({
        'empresa': self.request.user.cadastropessoas.id,
        'pk': self.kwargs['pk']
    })
    return kwargs
```

> forms.py

```
class ProdutoRceitaForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, empresa, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProdutoRceitaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.empresa_user = PessoasEmpresa.objects.get(pessoa=empresa)
        self.fields['produto'].queryset = Produto.objects.filter(
            ~Q(categoria=2),
            empresa=self.empresa_user.empresas
        )

    class Meta:
        model = ProdutoReceita
        fields = [
            'produto',
            'quantidade',
            'unidademedida',
            'obs'
        ]
```

> produtoreceita_form.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap %}

{% block principal%}
<div class="container">
   <form method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form |  bootstrap }}
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Adicionar</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

{% endblock %}

Answer (score 1):

`CreateView` deve ser usado só para criar objetos. Para editá-los você deve user `UpdateView` e ai sim passar o `id` do objeto que quer editar.

Na documentação da [`CreateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) e [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview) você pode ver a diferença entre elas.

Comment: eu passei o ID, pois preciso desse id para criar uma instancia no model. pois as tabelas estão N:M.